# find number sequence falls within ONE adjacent number (previous and next) by group

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Let `T={t|t=1,2,3..T}` be the time (sequence order number) For each group, at each `t` when/if a sequence occurs, we need to make sure the sequence (it is a number,let's assume it is `X`) is within the set of {`K-1,K,K+1`}, where `K` is the previous sequence number at `t-1`. For example, if the previous sequence number K=4, for the next sequence X, if  X fall within [3,4,5]. Then this X meet the requirement. If every X in the sequence meets the requirement, this group meets the require and labeled it TRUE.

I know the for loop can do the trick but I have large observations, it is very slow to do it in a loop. I known the `cummax` can help find the non-deceasing sequence quickly. I was wondering is there any quick solution like `cummax`.

```
seq <- c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,2,3,4)
group <- rep(letters[1:3],each=5)
dt <- data.frame(group,seq)

> dt
  group seq
1      a   1
2      a   2
3      a   1
4      a   2
5      a   3
6      b   1
7      b   2
8      b   3
9      b   1
10     b   2
11     c   1
12     c   2
13     c   2
14     c   3
15     c   4
```

The desired output:

```
y label
a:true
b:false
c:true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `diff` function to check if the adjacent sequence satisfies the condition:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(label = all(abs(diff(seq)) <= 1))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   group label
#  <fctr> <lgl>
#1      a  TRUE
#2      b FALSE
#3      c  TRUE
```

Here is the corresponding `data.table` version:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, .(label = all(abs(diff(seq)) <= 1)), .(group)]
```

Comment: I forget the diff. Thank you! I will check the speed for my data.

Comment: In `data.table` I would guess `setDT(dt)[, all(abs(seq - shift(seq, fill = 0)) < 2), by = group]` will be more idiomatic

Comment: @DavidArenburg Nice suggestion. Didn't test. But I think that will speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
is.sequence <- function(x)
    all(apply(head(cbind(x-1, x, x+1), -1) - x[-1] == 0, 1, any))

tapply(dt$seq, dt$group, is.sequence)
#    a     b     c 
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Why would you run `apply` within `tapply`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R example with `aggregate` and `diff`

```
    aggregate(c(1, abs(diff(dt$seq)) * (tail(dt$group, -1) ==
                                        head(dt$group, -1))),
              dt["group"], function(i) max(i) < 2)

  group     x
1     a  TRUE
2     b FALSE
3     c  TRUE
```

The first argument to `aggregate` is a vector that uses `diff` and turns the result on and off (to zero) based on whether the current adjacent vector elements are in the same group.

Comment: I don't see `ave` anywhere here, but maybe also `with(dt, tapply(seq, group, function(x) all(abs(diff(x)) < 2)))` could be a base alternative

Comment: You are right about `ave`. I used it in an early iteration and discarded it... This alternative looks great.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(seq~group,dt,  FUN = function(x) all(c(TRUE, 
                            abs((x[-1] - x[-length(x)])) <=1)))
#  group   seq
#1     a  TRUE
#2     b FALSE
#3     c  TRUE
```